# Getting error while making meteor-angular whatsapp tutorial: Controller 'ionTabs', required by directive 'ionTab', can't be found

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, meteor, angular-meteor

I was making the meteor angular2 whatsapp tutorial and I'm alredy stuck in STEP 1.
I created everything until listing 1.7 but my browser screams

`modules.js?hash=35d5037…:57565Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'ionTabs', required by directive 'ionTab', can't be found!`

Anyone has an idea what's going wrong here?